# How to use proftpd in SliTaz

Tags: linux, ftp, proftpd, ftps

I would like to use FTP over TLS on SliTaz. I’ve installed proftpd with the following command:

`tazpkg get-install proftpd`

I’m used to start and stop programs on SliTaz with `/etc/init.d/program start or stop` but I can’t figure out how to start proftpd because there is no /etc/init.d/proftpd.

The proftpd config is still default and I tried to connect with FileZilla but I get *Could not connect to sever* after authenticating the user.

The SliTaz (5.0) is a virtualmachine on a Windows 10 host. I tried with FileZilla on the host to the SliTaz host-only ip.

How can I configure proftpd on SliTaz?

*EDIT*

I figured out I can start proftpd with just typing `proftpd` in the command line. I do have a `/etc/proftpd.conf` file but when I change something in the file not changes. I cannot use `proftpd restart` so I assume proftpd reloads with just `proftpd`?

I tried using TLS with the following lines in `/etc/proftpd.conf`:

```sh
<IfModule mod_tls.c>                                                     
TLSEngine                  on                                            
TLSLog                     /var/log/proftpd/tls.log                      
TLSProtocol TLSv1.2                                                      
TLSCipherSuite AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH                                   
TLSOptions                 NoCertRequest AllowClientRenegotiations       
TLSRSACertificateFile      /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.pem             
TLSRSACertificateKeyFile   /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.pem              
TLSVerifyClient            off                                           
TLSRequired                on                                            
RequireValidShell          no                                            
</IfModule>
```

I created the proftpd.pem with `openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.pem -keyout /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.pem`

A normal FileZilla works perfect but a `Require explicit FTP over TLS` returns `500 AUTH not understood`.

*EDIT 2*

The mod_tls.c is not compiled by default. With `proftpd -l` I was able to see all the modules:

```sh
Compiled-in modules:
  mod_core.c
  mod_xfer.c
  mod_rlimit.c
  mod_auth_unix.c
  mod_auth_file.c
  mod_auth.c
  mod_ls.c
  mod_log.c
  mod_site.c
  mod_delay.c
  mod_facts.c
  mod_ident.c
  mod_cap.c
```

Mod_tls.c is not in the list and that is probably why it is not working. How do I add mod_tls.c to the proftpd list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone created a Proftpd TLS SliTaz package for FTPS. Install the package with:
`tazpkg get-install proftpd-tls`

You will be able to start and stop proftpd with:
`/etc/init.d/program start / stop`

The proftpd package will standard work without TLS. You must create certificates and configure them in the proftpd config file.

**Create the certificates:**

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.cert.pem -keyout /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.key.pem
```

**Configure proftpd with TLS:**

1. Open /etc/proftpd.conf and add: `Include /etc/proftpd/tls.conf`
2. Create `/etc/proftpd/tls.conf` and add:

```
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
  TLSEngine           on
  TLSLog              /var/log/proftpd/tls.log
  TLSProtocol         TLSv1.2
  TLSCipherSuite      AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH
  TLSOptions          AllowClientRenegotiations
  TLSRSACertificateFile     /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.cert.pem
  TLSRSACertificateKeyFile  /etc/proftpd/ssl/proftpd.key.pem
  TLSVerifyClient     off
  TLSRequired         off
  RequireValidShell   no
</IfModule>
```

3. Restart Proftpd: `/etc/init.d/program restart`

Proftpd works now with FTPS.

Special thanks to Mojo for creating the proftpd-tls package.